# Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle'

Tags: ipad, simulator

What is the error listed below?

> 2011-02-23 21:24:12.218 Success[7238:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/jimkillen12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/BAA5E0E7-AF12-4301-A4F8-1B9797C9E82D/Success.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow-iPad''

Answer (score 37):

One of your NIB file is missing from project, add the required NIB file:

In Build Phases

1. expand Copy Bundle Resources
2. click `+` at bottom
3. add the required NIB file.

Clean your build by `Shift+Cmd+K`, then run.

**P.S.** Also make sure to **use exact spelling** of NIB file while calling `initWithNibName:@"ViewNameController"`

**Probably**, you have named your NIB in a call by **lowercase letters** or you may have also included **extension .xib which is not required**.

Comment: I tried that, but it keeps appearing in red as if the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Its already added, though I am getting error. Can you please explain why?

Answer (score 13):

Probably, you have named your NIB in a call by lowercase letters. The simulator works fine in this case, but an iPhone device will return an error during runtime.

For example,

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"detailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

will fail. You need to change to:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc]
            initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: thanks! everything was indeed running fine on simulator... not sure why it should...

Comment: @Denis : You saved my day.

Answer (score 3):

In your Build Settings, Add Architecture =>>  armv6 and armv7

I just removed my error using this

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same problem, but it was because i wrote the extension .xib and it is not neccessary

```
token_view = [[GetToken alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetToken_iPad.xib" bundle:nil];
```

instead of

```
token_view = [[GetToken alloc] initWithNibName:@"GetToken_iPad" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there any warnings related to the NIB? This is usually do to an error in the NIB file (such as incorrect type of NIB).

Right click on the file and click "Get Info" to verify that the type is what you would expect.

Comment: Thank you!  The only thing that looks different when I open "Get Info" is the file path.  The one listed does not look like the one in the NIB error.

Comment: 'NSBundle </Users/jimkillen12/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/BAA5E0E7-AF12-4301-A4F8-1B9797C9E82D/Success.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow-iPad''  Instead the file path looks like this: /Users/jimkillen12/Downloads/DailySuccess/MainWindow.xib

Answer (score 1):

In my case was next:

I loaded in code XIB with name "??????Ipad" 
but XIB filename was           "??????IPad"

Answer (score 1):

An other possible issue: you are using **Base Localization on iOS 5** (caution, it kinda work on the iOS Simulator, but not on a device), but it is supported only starting from iOS 6.

For more info, see: [Could not load nib in bundle base internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700056/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-base-internationalization)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure your nib/xib file is included in the corresponding Target Membership.

Answer (score 1):

I Have Same Problem Just Follow Steps.

1.Copy your Project In Another Place.

2.Copy your NIB File Which Crash app.

3.Just Change Name

Ex. Old File Demo.xib Than Copy And Change Name DemoNew.xib

My Code is Below

Old Code

```
Demo *controller = [[Demo alloc]initWithNibName:@"Demo" bundle:nil];
```

I Just Change Name

```
Demo *controller = [[Demo alloc]initWithNibName:@"DemoNew" bundle:nil];
```

its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just check that file `MainWindow.xib` exist in your project. If not, just add the new interface file with name `MainWindow.xib`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a **collectionView cell** in a collection view which is picked up from a nib then you might be seeing the error" 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle "
When you are loading a collection view from a nib file, you do not have the option to declare a collection view cell on the nib unlike story board.
The correct way is to create a new custom cell , with a new nib and then load it on to the collection view.
**Note** : don't forget to register the nib of the new custom collection cell.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was "Incorrect name for nib file in:

```
collectionViewOutlet.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Recommend making all of them the same, the cell identifier and `nibName` as well so make it:

```
collectionViewOutlet.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

If it doesn't work try this:

```
Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources
```

You will find your `xib/storyborad` with red color.

Just remove it. Also, remove all references of the missing files from the project.

Now drag this `storyboard/xib` file again to this Copy Bundle Resources. It will still show you a file with red color but don't worry about it.

Command + Shift + K to clean the project and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using XCode 12.5 and Swift 5) the problem was that I choosed the NIBName based on the name of my ViewController:

```
let nibName = String(describing: type(of: self)) 
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
```

So I had "TestView.xib" and "TestViewController.swift". This mismatched and could only be resolved by renaming my ViewController to "TestView.swift".