# Could not load nib in bundle base internationalization

Tags: xcode, internationalization, nib, radix

I have a project that I created in xcode 4.5 with a target ios of 5.0 and I used Base Internationalization.  Base Internationalization moves the nib files to Base.lproj.

The project runs on my iPhone 4 running ios 6 and on my iPad 3 running ios 6.  But this error shows when I try to run it on my iPad 1 running ios 5.1.1.  In the Build Phase section of the target, the nib files are shown in red.

When I try to add the nib files to the Build Phases bundle resources, they add but they are still red (not found).  I have tried every way I know to add the nib files to the bundle resources.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

Base Internationalization is only supported in iOS 6. It will cause a crash in iOS 5 or below when it tries to load a Xib.

Note: Strangely, running on Simulator with iOS 5 will work. That should to be a bug.

I have detailed my experience after releasing my app with this dumb startup crash: http://samwize.com/2012/11/22/warning-do-not-use-base-internationalization-in-ios-5/

Answer (score 0):

I did not know that English (en) also must be localized.  When I localized English, I was able to load the nib files into the bundle.

I'm still getting 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MainViewController_iPad''

but at least now it's not because the nib files aren't in the bundle.