# Nib Load Failed

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode4

In my application, I made custom tab bar having 5 tabs, each tab shows different `UIViewController`.

Application is for iPhone only, so i made 2 NIBs for each `UIViewController` (if class name is DayView, NIBs are DayView_iPhone and DayView_iPhone5). Everything is working fine for up to 10 mins in the device as well as in simulator.

After that app is crashing showing this in console :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/kalyanasadinagarajugari/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/0DEBB118-BA67-440F-BA70-79ED41AC9134/CalendarBlender.app> (loaded)' with name 'DayView_iPhone''
```

I checked the NIB names also, every NIB file name is correct.

And my code is

```
NSString *nibName = [AppDelegate fetchNibWithViewControllerName:@"DayView"]; 
dayView = [[DayView alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];

if (IS_IPHONE_5) 
    dayView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 463); 
else
    dayView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 375); dayView.view.tag=2; [self.view      
addSubview:dayView.view];
```

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099707/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the Nibname (Case Sensitive) and clean the project,re run it . Did you changed the class name for all the nibs?

Comment: Every Nibname is perfect, i checked all the nibnames. My problem will occur after continously changing the tabs.

Comment: NSString *nibName = [AppDelegate fetchNibWithViewControllerName:@"DayView"];                dayView = [[DayView alloc] initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];
            if (IS_IPHONE_5)
                dayView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 463);
            else
                dayView.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 375);
            
                dayView.view.tag=2;
                [self.view addSubview:dayView.view];

Comment: this is how i calling, Is that any wrong in the code, and the nibnames are DayView_iPhone, DayView_iPhone5

Comment: add your code in your question .. so that we can understand it clearly.

Comment: Where did you written this code ? i.e in the DidfinishLaunchingwithoptions or where?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
   tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

   MyViewController* vc1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];
   MyOtherViewController* vc2 = [[MyOtherViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil];

   NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];
   tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
}
```

And you can add controllers dynamically too by adding controllers in tabBarController's array of viewControllers.