# Swift iOS Dynamic Tab bar from json response

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I'm new to iOS/Swift. My application is using a json data and I have to create tab bar using the json response. I mean, I get Array of Title from json and I have to create tab bar items based on that array. The Array data/count may change and the app should display the tab bar accordingly. I am trying to create the tab bar programatically without storyboards (as this is huge tab bar)

So far, I have tried the below code -

func tabBarCustom() {

```
    let tt = UITabBarController()

    var array1 = [UIViewController]()
    var controller1 = UIViewController()


    for i in 0..<navgTitle.count {

        controller1 = UIViewController(nibName: "WeatherViewController", bundle: nil)

        controller1.title = navgTitle[i]

    controller1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: navgTitle[i], image: .none, tag: 1)

        array1.append(controller1)



    }

    print(array1)

    tt.viewControllers = array1

    self.view.addSubview(tt.view)

}
```

The above code is failing saying - Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle' with name 'WeatherViewController'
I am not sure how to create multiple view controllers automatically using the title array, taking title as name of the view controller. is this possible? and how to loop in the array to create view controllers for each tab bar item

please help.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using nibs? If so, your project can't find the nib file, and you should check out this: [Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099707/could-not-load-nib-in-bundle-nsbundle). Or are you using Storyboard? If you are trying to initialize from the storyboard, you'll do something like this:

```
let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WeatherViewController")
```

(just be sure to add WeatherViewController as the view controller's identifier).

OR are you using code? If you are trying to create your view controller from code, you simply need to do WeatherViewController().

As for the tab bar, you're in the right direction it's just that creating the view controller is failing.

Comment: Thank you Caroline...I am not using the story board and tried with WeatherViewController(), it is working. However, I am still confused with two questions - 1. Am I supposed to create view controller for each tab? I mean in the 'for' loop how should I create view controller for each tab? OR how to handle each tab separately in 'WeatherViewController()'?     2. The 'More' button is not working in the tab bar, can you please let me know what should be the issue?      Hope you help me with the answers, thank you so much for your time..

Comment: Yes, you'll need to create a separate view controller for each item on your tab bar. You don't necessarily need to do it in a loop, something like this is more common:
```let mainVC = WeatherViewController()
let profileVC = ProfileViewController()
let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
tabBarController.viewControllers = [mainVC, profileVC]
```. I would check out this link here: https://learnappmaking.com/tab-bar-controller-uitabbarcontroller-swift-ios/. I'm not sure what you mean about the "More" button. If I've answered your original question, can you mark it as answered?

Comment: As I need to do the view controllers dynamically, is there a way to create them programatically? If I follow the same process that you mention, I need to create the vc's manually but my API always changes the data and they are not the same every time. That is why I was asking if I could do that dynamically (using the 'title' data from the API). Can you please let me know if this can be possible? Thanks

Comment: Yes you would just create or update the tab bar with the dynamic controllers you needed when you received the data from the API.